# How to use discord.py to check if an entry is made into audit logs and make decisions based on the data

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I want to my discord bot to see incoming audit log entries and do certain actions based on the entries' data while it's on.  Even after reading the documentation, I still have no clue on how to go about this.

How would the code look?

Answer (score 0):

There isnt currently event function to define actions for audit log but you can use audit log list with `Guild.audit_logs()` iterator to check available audits for example:

```
async for entry in guild.audit_logs(action=discord.AuditLogAction.ban):
print(f'{entry.user} banned {entry.target}')
```

For more information:
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html?highlight=audit_logs#discord.Guild.audit_logs
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html?highlight=audit_logs#audit-log-data

Comment: I have to omit the "async" because it throws an error.  When I do that, audit_logs() throws and error saying that it needs an argument "self".

This is the code so far:

from discord.ext import commands
import discord
import time

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', self_bot=True)
logs, entries = [], []

for entry in discord.Guild.audit_logs(action=discord.AuditLogAction.ban):
    print(f'{entry.user} banned {entry.target}')

^ Throws an error, audit_logs() needs self

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Logged in as {client.user}.  Ready to go.')